# appium presskey function not working android automation in karate

Tags: karate, appium-android

I'm currently working on a mobile automation POC using the karate framework, trying to automate the Amazon app on my Android device.

in the script I enter a text the automatic options are not showing up in the app. so I try to press an enter key using the `pressKeyCode` method in appium. I'm getting `pressKeyCode` is not a function issue

Please find the script here and help to perform Mobile keyboard actions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you could try adding Key.Enter after the text

```
* driver.input('elementbyid', 'text' + Key.ENTER)
```